# Geting all possible predicates between Entity types in DBpedia using Sparql

Tags: query-optimization, sparql

I am trying to get all the possible predicates that are possible in between two entity types. Below is the example for two entities with `Person` type.

```
SELECT distinct ?p 
WHERE { ?url1 rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> . 
        ?url2 rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> . 
        ?url1 ?p ?url2 . 
        FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?p), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology")).
      }
```

However, the resulting output consists of predicates like `birthPlace`, `deathPlace` which definitely cannot be in between two `Person` types.

Am I missing any constraints to get more logical outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether it's not worth to provide it as an answer ...

You're missing only one point:

The data in DBpedia is not perfect and free of noise since it's automatically extracted from Wikipedia.

You can check why this happens when you use

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
  ?url1 rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> . 
  ?url2 rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> . 
  ?url1 <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace> ?url2 . 
}
limit 10
```

Among others, you get

```
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                   url1                    |                                  url2                                  |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/Analía_Núñez  | http://dbpedia.org/resource/David                                      |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jorvan_Vieira | http://dbpedia.org/resource/Luís_Alves_de_Lima_e_Silva,_Duke_of_Caxias |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/Adebayo_Lawal | http://dbpedia.org/resource/Offa_of_Mercia+                            |
| ...                                       | ...                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Let's have a look at [http://dbpedia.org/resource/Analía_Núñez](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anal%C3%ADa_N%C3%BA%C3%B1ez):

```
DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Analía_Núñez>
```

Among others, it returns the triples

```
dbr:Analía_Núñez  dbo:birthPlace    dbr:Panama ,
                                    dbr:David ,
                  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/David,_Chiriqu\u00ED> .
```

You can see three birth places. While it should be http://dbpedia.org/resource/David,_Chiriqu%C3%AD , you can see that something went wrong during the extraction from the infobox
in the [Wikipedia article about Analía Núñez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anal%C3%ADa_N%C3%BA%C3%B1ez).